# Show Value in Vertical Axis using chart from Min ------ Max Value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, chart.js

Good Afternoon,
I am trying to draw chart in Laravel.
For Y Axis i need to put amount and on X Axis - Date.
I get min and max value for Y Axis. So need to get intermediate value with 50 Increment.

Say
Min Value is - 55 and Max Value = 550

Now want value start with 50-100-150-200-250-300-350-400-450-500-550-600

[image]

Thanks in Advance.....

While searching i found php range Function = $number = range(min, max, steps) say (55,550,50)...Can anyone help to use the same in controller file as i m getting  dd as                                                             -    array:1 [▼
0 => 1
]

Comment: While searching i found php range Function = $number = range(min, max, steps) say (55,550,50)...Can anyone help to use the same in controller file as i m getting    -    array:1 [▼
  0 => 1
]

Comment: I think chart.js can automatically create the steps. Check this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/linear-min-max.html

Comment: Thanks...Get it.....Coola